# Show matrices with given eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

What should I do next to show such $A$, $B$ of size $2\times2$ that for all $t \in \Bbb R$ the matrix $A+tB$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_{1,2} (t) = \pm \sqrt t$?

At the moment, I got this:
$$tr(A+tB)=\sqrt t - \sqrt t$$
$$tr(A)+t \cdot tr(B)=0$$
$$(a_{11}+a_{22})+t(b_{11}+b_{22})=0$$

Comment: What are the elements of these matrices? Real numbers? Complex number? Is $A+tB$ meant to have complex eigenvalues when $t\lt0$?

Comment: @amd no given information about that.

Comment: @Bungo I came up with an example that fits the condition of the problem: suppose $A$ will be $[0, 1, 0, 0]$ and $B$ will be $[0, 0, 1, 0]$. After finding eigenvalues, we get: $\lambda^2=t$. It should be right for any given $t$.